# HTTP authentication not working with passport-http

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm following a tutorial to create my first login-system with passport, and I've run into a problem with passports 'basic' strategy.

The problem is that my code does not block entries to the `/api` directory at all, and I don't understand why.

My code looks like this:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var passportLocal = require('passport-local');
var passportHttp = require('passport-http');

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

    passport.use(new passportHttp.BasicStrategy(verifyCredentials));

    function verifyCredentials(username, password, done){
      if (username === password){
        done(null, { id: username, name: username });
      } else {
        done(null, null);
      }
    }

    app.use('/api', passport.authenticate('basic'));
```

The weird thing is that it worked the first time I ran it, but afterwards it didn't, so I'm wondering if there's an issue somewhere else but in my code.

Any suggestions on what's wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I know what happens.

Your browser is caching the user and password. Try opening an incognito window with Chrome, and opening that url. It should ask you the password again.

AFAIK Chrome only clears cached HTTP auth when it closes. So you should be opening and closing incognito windows for each test...

Comment: Im happy that helped! Can you accept please the answer so we close this question? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative I suggest to use [http-auth](http://http-auth.info) with passport integration:

```
// Authentication module.
var auth = require('http-auth');
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
    file: __dirname + "/../data/users.htpasswd" // gevorg:gpass, Sarah:testpass ...
});

// Application setup.
var app = express();

// Setup strategy.
var passport = require('passport');
passport.use(auth.passport(basic));

// Setup route.
app.get('/', passport.authenticate('http', { session: false }), function(req, res) {
    res.end("Welcome to private area - " + req.user + "!");
});
```